# Handling callback in .NET Core API

Tags: c#, .net, api, .net-core, callback

I have an .NET Core web api project. In this project, I use external REST services and one of these services the result of OTP is sent via callback to the provided endpoint.
Let's think that I have an OTP auth page. When the user enter valid OTP, the result of the process will be sent as a callback where I provide the endpoint. At the moment, I am testing the process via online webhook tool.

How can I handle the callback on my self in my .NET Core web api?

I am trying to get the response which will be sent as callback.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by handling the callback? Do you mean when you send a request to your own API you want to be able to return a callback in a form of a status message?

Comment: @Bram No :). The url that is getting invoked does a post-back with the result. How would you catch that post-back in the current code executing context.

Comment: Oww wait, you mean you are getting a response back after you send a request, and you want to catch that result? If so, how are you making these requests? Using an HTTP client?

Comment: @Silvermind exactly, at the moment I am calling the endpoint with the Process, but I will change it with client post request. But I do not know how can I handle the returned response.

Comment: I can give the endpoint to the request where the response will be sent. But I cannot figure out the process in which way I can catch the response and handle.